# Google Image search using an image URL

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, google-search, google-image-search

I have tried searching this multiple times and came across no simple resources.

Lets say I have a single URL and I want to search for all images that look the same as said image (let's say <98% similarity, for arguments sake).

I simply want to return the number of images that look the same as my original, that is all.

I have [searched Google multiple times](https://www.google.ie/search?espv=210&es_sm=93&sclient=psy-ab&q=google%20search%20by%20image%20url%20api%20example&oq=google%20search%20by%20image%20url%20api%20example&gs_l=serp.3..33i29i30.117350.119264.1.119374.8.8.0.0.0.0.246.1168.0j2j4.6.0....0...1c.1.29.psy-ab..10.21.4033.dTpsi7VjDJ4&pbx=1&biw=1366&bih=624&cad=cbv&sei=n7RuUsbIBqqO7Abw9IHwCw#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=google%20search%20by%20image%20url%20api%20python%20example) ,but found no convenient way for me to do this using. I would preferably like to use Python, but if this is not possible it would be perfect if I could just use the method call in a Python program.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api 

Suggestion was: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: Hmmm... read through it, and it doesn't look like they have an API exposed for reverse image search. As @SteinarLima suggested, tineye.com is a good choice, or you can possibly scrape the results from http://images.google.com (probably just a simple form to POST to and then scrape the results). Would web services solve your problem, or are you looking for more algorithm related answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for all images you have through google image search engine simply, because Google has been providing us with their own APIs like

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images`

And I found related article on stackoverflow, just take a look at [python search with image google images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242967/python-search-with-image-google-images)

Comment: I'm not sure the API's are exposed for that particular Google product - only normal image search. This was a decent article on coming close by scraping the result pages:

http://skyzerblogger.blogspot.com/2013/01/google-reverse-image-search-scraping.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem more suitable for a web-service to perform. [Tineye.com](https://tineye.com/) is a reverse image search, and I suspect that you can use curl to send a http request to this web service, and use e.g. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract the number of matches.