# download images with google custom search api

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, google-custom-search

I have used google image api in python  to download 20 first image result with the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib2
import simplejson



searchTerm = "Cat"

# Replace spaces ' ' in search term for '%20' in order to comply with request
searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(' ','%20')



# Start FancyURLopener with defined version 
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener): 
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
myopener = MyOpener()

# Set count to 0
count=0

for i in range(0,4):
    # Notice that the start changes for each iteration in order to request a new set of images for each loop
  url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?'+'v=1.0&q='+searchTerm7+'&start='+str(i*4)+'&userip=MyIP&imgsz=xlarge|xxlarge|huge')
  print url
  request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
  response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    # Get results using JSON
  results = simplejson.load(response)
  data = results['responseData']
  dataInfo = data['results']

    # Iterate for each result and get unescaped url
  for myUrl in dataInfo:
    count = count + 1
    print myUrl['unescapedUrl']
    os.chdir(newpath)
    myopener.retrieve(myUrl['unescapedUrl'],str(num)+'-'+str(count))

    # Sleep for one second to prevent IP blocking from Google
    time.sleep(3)
```

But now i would like to use google custom search to do that, in order to get better result. I have understand that i should register to get a APIKey but i did'nt find any simple example as the code i post. Does some one can help, i am really lost in the google documentation.

Visibly there is restriction for the free api, 100 request a day, is that correct?

Edit: I am here rightnow, but still not work

```
import os
import sys
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib2
import simplejson
import cStringIO
import pprint


searchTerm="Cat"

# Start FancyURLopener with defined version 
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener): 
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
myopener = MyOpener()


url='https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve'+'&q='+searchTerm+'&searchType=image'+'&start=0'+'&imgSize=xlarge|xxlarge|huge'
print url
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    # Get results using JSON

data = json.load(response)
pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint(data['items'][0])
```

Comment: did you get this to work ? How are you doing it now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this [Google APIs Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) Library for Python.

**Demo:**

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/customsearch/main.py) is a sample (i change it to):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

service = build("customsearch", "v1",
               developerKey="** your developer key **")

res = service.cse().list(
    q='butterfly',
    cx=' ** your cx **',
    searchType='image',
    num=3,
    imgType='clipart',
    fileType='png',
    safe= 'off'
).execute()

if not 'items' in res:
    print 'No result !!\nres is: {}'.format(res)
else:
    for item in res['items']:
        print('{}:\n\t{}'.format(item['title'], item['link']))
```

**Output:**

```
Clipart - Butterfly:
        http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/3965/jonata_Butterfly.png
Animal, Butterfly, Insect, Nature - Free image - 158831:
        http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/13/11/51/animal-158831_640.png
Clipart - Monarch Butterfly:
        http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/110023/Monarch_Butterfly_by_Merlin2525.png
```

Yes, there is a limitation for `Free` edition and you can [monitor it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtusH.png) from Google developer console:

[image: here]

**Note:**

Go to your [Custom Search Engine](https://www.google.com/cse/all), then select your [custom search engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuOMj.png), then in [Basics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRBWH.png) tab,
set `Image search` option to `ON`, and for `Sites to search` section, select `Search the entire web but emphasize included site` option.

**Links:**

- https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/customsearch/v1/python/latest/customsearch_v1.cse.html
- https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list
- https://www.google.com/cse/all
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/customsearch/v1
- https://console.developers.google.com/project
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys

Comment: Thxa lot. But how can i save easly the image in  a folder? There is probably a sample... I haven't still finde

Comment: You can use [urllib.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3042786/538284) is an example.

Comment: In fact it seems i can't get res with your code wince I get the following error:
 for item in res['items']:
KeyError: 'items'

Comment: Check `Note` section of my answer.

Comment: Do you know how I can get more than the first 10 results from this query? Works beautifully, but I'd love to see more than just 10 results…

Comment: ah, got it. add parameter "start = 20" to get the next 10

Answer (score 0):

I have search api for downloading images to create data set of images may be you should have a look at these !

1. https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search?endpoint=5b864ca4e4b085e3f407ecca
2. https://github.com/hardikvasa/webb/blob/master/docs/Documentation.md

From documentation i like the 2nd one to perfect !