# image size on customsearch api

Tags: google-custom-search

Is there is a way to search image "larger than 400*300" as in google image with a customsearch in command line (python). The only options I have found for ImgSize are :icon,small, medium, xlarge, xxlarge and huge.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

`tbs=...` appears to be a comma-separated list of `filter:value` entries which the search should use. For "larger than 400*300", use `tbs=isz:lt`.

You can find more of these values by simply applying filters and checking the value of this parameter in the resulting requests.

<s>This may not be directly relevant. Could you clarify what you're trying to do and where?</s>

Looking at a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866579) you asked, is this question also regarding the [Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/)?

Comment: when i put 
`res = service.cse().list(
        q= app+s,
        cx='my_cx',
        searchType='image',
        num=10,
        start=str(10*i+1),
        tbm=isch,
        tbs=isz:lt,islt:qsvga
      ).execute() `
I got the following error 
`tbs=isz:lt,islt:qsvga
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 `