# How to scrap only the first image got from google search result?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Let's say , I searched Dog Images on Google. I will get certain results. I just want to scrap the first image of dog.

I want to do this with python code, such that , in function I will just provide "Dog" and it should provide me the link of first image?

Comment: Show us what you have tried until now - what code did you write to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends.

```py
def grab_links():
   # if you have results stored in a list
   results = [] #list of links
   return results[0] # return 1st element
```

Comment: But, how to fetch the result from google search results?

Comment: There are multiple options available 
* https://pypi.org/project/google_images_download/
* https://pypi.org/project/icrawler/

you could also implement the same with HTTP clients like requests, urllib3 or httpx

Comment: This might help for implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809554/how-to-download-google-image-search-results-in-python

Comment: Thanks Bhaskar N
Your icrawler suggestion is working
But, the images are downloaded in my folder. I want list of urls of image. Can you plz tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Well, Looks like icrawler doesn't have an API for that. Reference custom implementation can be found here https://github.com/hellock/icrawler/issues/73