# Google Search by Image Script for Local Images

Tags: python, image, search, scripting

I'm searching a script for finding similar images to my local images. Actually, I have searched similar topic on stackoverflow but I could not find any solution or clue for my problem.

The topic which is in following url is similar to my problem but it searches with using texts. 
[python search with image google images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242967/python-search-with-image-google-images)

I think that I must pass my local images to my http request as raw bytes but I did not find how can I do that.

Finally, I tried to upload my local images to the web and search with using urls but this time I faced the following problem:

When I searched [this image](https://www.google.com.tr/doodle4google/2013/images/doodles/winner.png) with its url, google generates this url:

https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivZoXHOHzWl5_1BGnG05Bm1LpdXCjewepYnpAH4Xi-s7fVU0S86XG4MFlP7hYlGUpioWaZSjwBBIRDOXrGL8uum9wurfEZowKDUl_1GMPE8JHOO5vEb_1iMSbkmvqx-sWxbPqeHeW1eeJPDgtjio_1l7sJcvSbIquQOoacs3x1mDiF7OLw0mNA3WdR59dFDZAwlpU9A2cXbk_1RrqcilNOEcf0osSDx6TDtXN9ndN3ZSFF8NQhHVDPRrjqRpETbXpVHtyJiIxTzLeAiSC-POpwwN1I3tutScJISO72ZhLCUMAZ-gAuuaTHiHQq-vJBcAgq_1zfzwrDxncCVaKBlqb-zDHclm_1tc9qAMlIIsuKvGXnOSY9flVL4Nqk6Js8Un7_1P_1MbkgVCOcWRmbKG0E_1Sl_145Xe-las_18k4e0N0Ar9eKWGd5gvO33ai967E1tj8uiBqfjZTDYUC_1UARgU-IedUIU4uTmpLgK2xMBTXbSgLU8LdW5ZmB1p_1Tm7tpyIczoN23B2AJz9tFp1wnVOeCi_1jOcegCMPxw_1pULXDVWmgd_1f1OMX_1OrLl7wq5VZbBnH3ME62tdKCScZySq7_11Rx7zvzf2JTKQ_16jt_1HJ2Nf6mYb77n58TSMOSbxNvlCnT6afbPHN_101-Xrb2o0QnkESNBMKNwhLg2ZDDgRSgO0gvyzn86FAIR4Eif77PMV0IlEXtaizdveGwCN3upch2XZQpzljgMOUD0ZEfpe_1GxysMuetPZe_12MsYFp2EVW_19oFqTiavEtn2LIcBI1jhow5zWCkwmcNv8Dz80qYTLCRcAaj5l5w2DsdJd8IiufYP0qxKb5pwXbdM0k3-jEQVaWBo_1wK4dohn3UierX63up9YZWNfKNciTjecJ2q69b9xkhtXp_1LWt9Sdi8-xt25FS1XkW6VdVuqhX9-OexZ9G8bV1SgOEHx5GOuCkdsBjqBZ_1Df9wDGLKDX4V9BVvpX_13TLn6YNFtkHR70z_1zaG66rHPun-fWygzsO_1uSmJH5BtcQODEOSJ7jCs_1iSJf--RB339DBzLenbJB_1HUVPiC7Tj0BvbnWtLnY9sElHi5jPprOlqfVa9uQe21eymwXZROi4aWwhByeODCsCfZjjUNoi0M_1pCTva4KW6mlmrWshh9h_1_1kl3Wx7sKpHGBqIY7VJ8pG3kcp7x0YtbPmfxF6J2iKoMzKHyutTx3cn5PJY9kZhOYs5RCs9ejC0Vmw42qdQaivEUB1aQazxRYH-knaGcbANS0p2OacI32X1SrwWoOdodj733y5_1jJi2soZi4COkUjG_18_1c028sLlBkdVkedcq8DXbUEcQB5jIQPx1115aZqdn8SzSLGxLhowIlVxq6kLuyXuLJy72kArT91Rol2v5jHFxapFjrNuDgwdirVQQIsbx_1jXzgTVPdhYV08eFdpnVnsVu3OaUNZPZO8gsSs9A

I expected a url like google.com/search?url={image_url} but it isn't. Hence, I cannot generate a script for searching my local images.

How can I solve my problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also see [Google image search: How do I construct a reverse image search URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url)

Comment: thanks @LukasGraf these are solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

Use the following url 
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=
and concatenate your image URL to it.